# How to expand and interpolate grouped data in dataframe with the equal number of interpolation points for each group using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, sequence, interpolation

I would like to interpolate values in a dataframe by groups such that every group has the same amount of data points.

So far, I tried a couple of things around the expand() and na.approx() functions but did not succeed.

It is easiest to understand with an example: I would like to convert this dataframe:

```
> df.test
  ID  x   y
1  A  0 9.0
2  A  2 8.0
3  B 10 1.0
4  B 20 1.5
5  B 30 3.0
```

to this

```
> df.test.result
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   ID        x     y
   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A       0    9   
 2 A       0.5  8.75
 3 A       1    8.5 
 4 A       1.5  8.25
 5 A       2    8   
 6 B      10    1   
 7 B      15    1.25
 8 B      20    1.5 
 9 B      25    2.25
10 B      30    3
```

The idea is to create 5 data points each of group A and B where the missing y values are determined by linear interpolation. For instance, for group "B" it should interpolate at x=15, x=25 (10,20,30 are already there) to get five points. To get x=15, it should linearly interpolate the y-values of the closest datapoints (in this case x=10 and x=20). And as in this example x=15 is in the middle of the two, this would give (x,y)=(15,1.25).

For a start, I expanded the groups (to receive NAs in y column to be interpolated later) by

```
  df.test.expand <- df.test %>%
                      group_by(ID) %>%
                      expand(x=full_seq(x,1)) %>% 
                      ungroup() %>% 
                      left_join(df.test)
```

but then the x column is always incremented by 1 and I do not get an the same sample size (e.g. 5 elements) for each group.

Is there any more direct way to do this interpolation?

I imagine, it is a common problem that should be straightforward in dplyr.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 summarise_all(~ list(seq(first(.), last(.), len = 5))) %>%
 unnest()

   ID        x     y
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A       0    9   
 2 A       0.5  8.75
 3 A       1    8.5 
 4 A       1.5  8.25
 5 A       2    8   
 6 B      10    1   
 7 B      15    1.5 
 8 B      20    2   
 9 B      25    2.5 
10 B      30    3
```

To perform a linear interpolation (also using `zoo`):

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 complete(x = seq(first(x), last(x), len = 5)) %>%
 mutate(y = na.approx(y))

   ID        x     y
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A       0    9   
 2 A       0.5  8.75
 3 A       1    8.5 
 4 A       1.5  8.25
 5 A       2    8   
 6 B      10    1   
 7 B      15    1.25
 8 B      20    1.5 
 9 B      25    2.25
10 B      30    3
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This way both columns obtain equally spaced samples but the relationship between x and y that should be interpolated is ignored. I have not made that clear in the question, I think, due to my example. I updated it now. I really want to interpolate between each datapoint, where only the x coordinate should be uniformly incremented. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!